# Create public forward proxies,

Tags: nginx, proxy

I'm eager to set up a process where I can send requests from my a client to mainip:1000, route them through proxyip1 to the internet, and then have the responses return to the main IP and finally to the client. (I think that i'm looking for reverse natting but can't find anything on that for my situation.)

The source IP for incoming requests can be any IP (i have multiple pc's in a the public domain), and the destination IP for the proxy IP is not pre determined.

Is this feasible with Nginx Proxy Manager, could you guide me on how to configure it for this purpose?

However, if Nginx Proxy Manager isn't the right tool for the job, I'd love to hear your suggestions.

Please note that at the moment, there is no active NAT configuration in place, so all IPs involved are public IPs.

I have a /28 ipv4 subnet and a VPS with 1 NIC.

Looking forward to your insights and expertise!

Comment: Software recommendations are off topic on ServerFault. Nginx Proxy Manager isn't suitable as it's for the *reverse* proxy control. Also, to understand the problem we need to know how many clients are there — 10, 100, 1000? For small number you can really go with any forward proxy software (just STFW for that).